# Extra spaces appending in Spooling SQL script in UNIX

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, sqlplus, spool

I am trying to generate a datafile as downlaod of a table, which is possiby in fixed format.
I already have the SQL ready.

**Example:**

```
SELECT RPAD(ORGANIZATION_ID,10)||RPAD(ORGANIZATION_NAME,100)||RPAD(EMPLOYEE_COUNT,100)
FROM MY_ORGANIZATION_STATE;
```

I run it in a SQL Developer, and export into Excel. for sample of 50 records.
Am able to fetch is correctly, and the format looks OK.

But I need to automate it, and hence we use SQL*Plus's spool command.
A snippet is below.

```
set pagesize 100;
set linesize 10000;
set heading off;
spool orgn_output.dat;
@my_script # this has my SQL inside
spool off;
```

This runs without any error.

But when i tried to open the file, I could see, extra spaces are inside the file, and the layout is not as i expected!

When i run the SQL manually, and spool using PUTTY, it look file. Why does my script generates a wrong one. I have no clue, why it happens.

ANy help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** Output:

```
100         Deva@Company@Sales          469
101         Deva@School                 234
102         Deva@Hospitals              245
103         Deva@Company@Finance        469
```

Thanks

Comment: Actually, issueing cut -c command in unix, clearly shows the layout is wrong.

Comment: i tried my own with an example!

Comment: Extra spaces at the end of each line, or between values? Does `set tab off` affect what you're seeing? That might be making some of the alignment go off. If the lines are too long, you might need `set trimspool on` but I'm not sure if that's relevant?

Comment: @AlexPoole cheers... i was able to identify the same.. it worked for me!

Comment: @AlexPoole you are right! U guys are awesome.. I was struggling lot with this question.. Was researching issues over UNICODe related!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar thanks, Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I am able to recreate your issue easily. It happens when the column text is lesser. when i issue exact text size, the layout is size, and I am seeing the text inside the spooled text has tab characters instead if spaces. The pattern is not consistent too. I just researched with available command, and I found. `SET TAB OFF`; in sqlplus solves this.

I hope, `sqlplus` itself is changing multiple spaces inside into TAB. Setting TAB solved it.!

Please try that option. and let me know. Good luck!

**P.S**. Editting your question, revealed the bug, possibly SO, converts TAB effectively while formatting :)

Comment: you are right! U guys are awesome.. I was struggling lot with this question.. Was researching issues over UNICODe related!

Comment: @DevarajMahesan - the SQL*Plus documentation has various sections about formatting; including the behaviour of [`set tab`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2683445). Helps if you already know what you're looking for, of course *8-)

Comment: Devaraj - not sure if trailing spaces are a problem too, but if they are you should also `SET TRIMSPOOL ON`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have this kind of problem with sqlplus. After i have fixed it i would like to recommend you to try with this format of sqlplus.

1. SET TRIMSPOOL ON;
2. SET TAB OFF;

Due to the error , Because it is about the spool issue. So we just take the format of the trimspool on.